# Clean directive not working in makefile

Tags: unix, makefile

I am writing a makefile for my program "p1", but I can't get my "clean" to work.

```
#Default target
p1: main.o bst_insert.o bst_info.o
    gcc main.o bst_insert.o bst_info.o -o p1

#START Dependencies for default target
main.o: const.h bst_insert.h bst_info.h bst_struct_def.h main.c
    gcc -c main.c

bst_insert.o: bst_struct_def.h bst_insert.h bst_insert.c
    gcc -c bst_insert.c

bst_info.o: bst_struct_def.h bst_info.h bst_info.c
    gcc -c bst_info.c
#END Dependencies for default target

#Target for removing unnecessary files.
clean:
    rm -f *.o core
```

Here is the before/after:

[image: make_before_after]

For whatever reason, "clean" never executes. Can someone tell me why? I'm new to makefiles so I could be making a very obvious mistake that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run it manually: `make p1 clean`

Besides, your Make file could have been much shorter.

```
p1: bst_info.o bst_insert.o bst_struct_def.o
        gcc $^ -o $@

clean:
        rm -f *.o
```

Comment: Okay, so it's never supposed to run on its own - it must be explicitly called?

Comment: I didn't see this in the project readme before: `When we run make with clean as the target, it should delete all the ".o" files and the file named core (if any).`. I thought the clean target had to run automatically after p1 was created.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't give it a specific target to build on the command line, then make will always build the first target in the makefile.  It will ensure that target is up to date by checking all its prerequisites, and their prerequisites, etc. and ensuring they're up to date, then building the target (if needed).

Any targets which are not part of that tree will not be built unless you specifically request it.  So in this example, `clean` is not the first target, and it's not a prerequisite of the first target, etc. so it's not built.  If you want it built you should run `make clean` to request that it be built, or you need to add it into the prerequisite list.  However, doing that is tricky because you want it run *last*.  So you'd need to do something like this:

```
clean: p1
        rm -f *.o
```

as the first target.  Now `clean` will be run, but before that can happen `p1` will be built, etc.

However, this is very unusual and unlikely to be what you want.  The entire point of having a makefile is so that you only have to recompile the files that have changed and not recompile the files you haven't changed.  If you delete all the object files every time, then every time you run make it will have to recompile everything.

If you always want everything recompiled every time, then `make` is useless.  You might as well just write a shell script that will compile your code then delete all the objects.